# Android implementation service and launch in background also if the application is died

Tags: android

I am trying to find how to enable the application to perform a background task.
I use the example seen here "http://saigeethamn.blogspot.fr/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-part-9.html" and I do not know if that is how I have proceed to execute a script permanently?
Also how to get it reactivated when starting the mobile?
So how should we do and if we can so that the service works even if you force stopping the application?

A big thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

No service can work if the user force stops an application.  Force stopping puts the entire app into a state where no services, receivers, or activities can be run unless the user explicitly does so.

If you want to start a service when the phone starts, you need a broadcast receiver for the BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast.

Comment: Thanks ! And the exemple of site how I use is good to implement the service ?